# Permissions Error when trying to run a script in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, permissions, file-permissions, permission-denied

I am trying to run a script in python and I got this error:

```
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'E:\\Projects\\Abusive Comments Filter\\zest.txt'
```

main.py

```
import re
import tkinter as tk
import subprocess
import urllib.request
from inscriptis import get_text

import os

BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
path1 = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'Abusive-Comments-Filter-master/zest.txt')

# url = input("Enter URL\n")
url = "https://www.quora.com/What-are-all-the-bad-words-and-their-meanings"
html = urllib.request.urlopen(url).read().decode('utf-8')

text = get_text(html)
path = r'path1'
# path = ''
file = open(path, 'w')
file.write(text)
file.close()
```

How can i fix this please.

Answer (score 1):

Close the file `zest.txt` if it is open in your text editor or any other program.

Comment: which file please.

Comment: The file you are trying to access, `zest.txt`

Comment: the file doesn't exist there

Comment: Hi could you elaborate, are you trying to create a file or read it, could you post your code please

Comment: oh ok but then what did you mean when you said "the file doesn't exist there", you cannot read a file if it is not there and your python script cannot open the file if it is exists but is already open in another program.

Comment: i cloned the project on github and was trying to run it when i came through this bug. maybe the owner did not share the file.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229771/discussion-between-abhi-j-and-coderboy).